# How to uninstall ccminer?

Tags: ccminer

I installed the ancient `tsiv` version of ccminer and I want to switch to one that's maintained. When I check `which ccminer` I see that it lives in `/usr/local/bin/ccminer`. There are no uninstall directions-- what's the correct way to uninstall it? `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ccminer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that will work. if you have the source code still, you can try

> make uninstall

or

> sudo make uninstall

from inside the source code directory. check out https://askubuntu.com/a/87112/610029